# How to share a text with minimum n number of people on whatsapp using Android Intent System

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I know how to share some text from my application to whatsapp using intent.
But I want to make sure that user shares the text with minimum n number of contacts like 5 or 10.
How can I do that?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: and the answer is : you can not control how your intent is handled in respective apps. yes, the answer is **NO**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that my friend , Whats app is a very closed app even when it was merged with Facebook it stopped all existing APIs.

Comment: But I think I saw some apps prompting us to share certain message with fixed number of people so I was wondering if it is possible

Comment: before sept 2016 there was an api for whats app but it was stopped after merging with Facebook. I am pretty sure that it is impossible right now but if you found a way please tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

that is not possible with whatsapp for now